# Free SSH Client for Nokia S60 (Nokia 5800) / Symbian

Tags: ssh, remote-access, terminal, nokia, symbian

I want to ssh-login to linux servers from the road in emergencies. I have a Nokia 5800 phone which runs symbian.

I downloaded this telnet/ssh client from Mochasoft http://www.mochasoft.org/telnet60.sis - but the phone brings up an error message telling me it does not support installation of telnet60.sis

Is there some open source ssh client for this phone or another client which is preferrably free. I would also pay if open source is not available.

Or is there some trick to install the client from Mochasoft?

**Edit:** Now I installed the putty version for Symbian 5th edition from http://bd.kicks-ass.net/koodaus/putty/ and I am quite happy with it. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I get "Expired certificate" when trying to install the koodaus putty on my 5800XM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Putty for Symbian OS](http://s2putty.sourceforge.net/). Works on S60 and S80.

Comment: Gotta make sure your phone is S60 3rd edition (or higher) though. Normal S60 won't run 3rd edition programs. The 5800 is 5th edition, but others (like myself) might not be so lucky.

Comment: Sure, but I had a 3rd edition phone over 2 years ago, so I assume this isn't a problem for most people these days.

Answer (score 1):

I found that MidpSSH works well on mobile phones. I believe that it will run on the Nokia 5800. http://www.xk72.com/midpssh/download.php. It is difficult to read 80 columns of text on a 320 pixel-wide screen, but on the 640 pixel resolution of the 5800 it should be a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a helpful blog post http://brainchunk.blogspot.com/2009/06/putty-on-nokia-5800.html

Answer (score 0):

There is Putty for s60v3 and s60v5 and it support port forwarding (SSH tunnel) too.
look at this:
http://my-symbian.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39104&view=previous&sid=27b0ef236e0f269bfb3c04e4d02ac2ff